# issue with createInput in p5

Tags: javascript

I am trying and rather liking JS p5 but I am currently really struggling.

I have created a global variable named **name**. In the setup I try to make it an input by using **createInput();**.

Whenever I try and modify the input like the coordinates, I get the error like **name.position** is not a function.

After investigating I can create the input if I create the input inside the setup but the problem is I need to hide the input until a certain event but because I have created the variable inside the setup I cannot call it outside by using name.show().

I have no idea what is wrong. I can create variables and make them buttons just fine but not for inputs. I have the current libraries needed to use these functions.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share your code, what you have tried so far. This will help in understanding question more clearly and providing answers.

Comment: var button; 
var json = {};
var name; 
function setup() {
    createCanvas(innerWidth, innerHeight); 
     setPos(); 
    setPlayer(); 
    spawnEnemie(); 
    button = createButton("Save and reset"); 
    button.position(width/2,height/2); 
    button.mousePressed(reset);
    button.hide(); 
    name = createInput(''); 
    name.position(width/2 ,height/2 +60);
    name.changed(saveName);
    name.hide();  
  
}

Comment: the error I get is name.show is not a function